# Why do not these items appear on firefox browser?

Tags: html, css, browser

I have this page:

http://paul.dac-proiect.ro/

In Chrome all is well but look as displayed in Firefox.

[image]

```
      <div class="social" style="float:right">
               <div id="facebook"></div>
               <div id="twitter"></div>
               <div id="link"></div>
       </div>
```

```css
.pozitie{position: absolute;top: 200px;left: 39;color:#f9f9f9;"}

/* IMAGINI HOVER SOCIAL MEDIA */    
#facebook {
   background-image: url("http://placehold.it/26x26");
   width:26px;
   height:26px;
   float:left;
margin-right:5px;

}
#facebook:hover {
   background-image: url("http://placehold.it/26x26");
}

#link{
   background-image: url("http://placehold.it/26x26");
   width:26px;
   height:26px;
   float:left;

}
#link:hover {
   background-image: url("http://placehold.it/26x26");
}

#twitter{
   background-image: url("http://placehold.it/26x26");
   width:26px;
   height:26px;
   float:left;
   margin-right:5px;

}
#twitter:hover {
   background-image: url("http://placehold.it/26x26");
}
```

```html
<div class="social" style="float:right">
  <div id="facebook"></div>
  <div id="twitter"></div>
  <div id="link"></div>
</div>
```

I tried to clean the cache but nothing has changed.
Does anyone have any idea where this problem occurs?

Comment: where is doctype in your page? try adding <!doctype html>
<html> before <head>

Comment: You have a lot of issues with your CSS https://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/validator?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fpaul.dac-proiect.ro%2Fwp-content%2Fthemes%2Fwpbootstrap%2Fstyle.css&profile=css3&usermedium=all&warning=1&vextwarning=&lang=en. The issue would appear to be due to `.pozitie{position: absolute;top: 200px;left: 39;color:#f9f9f9;"}` which is causing styles to be skipped in FF. Try removing the unnecessary `"` e.g. `.pozitie{position: absolute;top: 200px;left: 39;color:#f9f9f9;}`

Comment: For future reference please can you provide all the relevant code in your question to allow us to reproduce the issue. If the link dies this question will be of no use.

Comment: @Cristi Glad I could help, I've edited your question to include all the code required to replicate the issue and posted my comment as an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is due to an extra `"` in the class `.pozitie` which is causing Firefox to ignore subsequent rules. Remove `"` and the rules should then take effect.

**Current incorrect syntax - Wont work in Firefox:**

```css
.pozitie{position: absolute;top: 200px;left: 39;color:#f9f9f9;"}
  
/* IMAGINI HOVER SOCIAL MEDIA */

#facebook {
  background-image: url("http://placehold.it/26x26");
  width: 26px;
  height: 26px;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 5px;
}
#facebook:hover {
  background-image: url("http://placehold.it/26x26");
}
#link {
  background-image: url("http://placehold.it/26x26");
  width: 26px;
  height: 26px;
  float: left;
}
#link:hover {
  background-image: url("http://placehold.it/26x26");
}
#twitter {
  background-image: url("http://placehold.it/26x26");
  width: 26px;
  height: 26px;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 5px;
}
#twitter:hover {
  background-image: url("http://placehold.it/26x26");
}
```

```html
<div class="social" style="float:right">
  <div id="facebook"></div>
  <div id="twitter"></div>
  <div id="link"></div>
</div>
```

**New correct syntax - Will work in Firefox:**

```css
/* IMAGINI HOVER SOCIAL MEDIA */

#facebook {
  background-image: url("http://placehold.it/26x26");
  width: 26px;
  height: 26px;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 5px;
}
#facebook:hover {
  background-image: url("http://placehold.it/26x26");
}
#link {
  background-image: url("http://placehold.it/26x26");
  width: 26px;
  height: 26px;
  float: left;
}
#link:hover {
  background-image: url("http://placehold.it/26x26");
}
#twitter {
  background-image: url("http://placehold.it/26x26");
  width: 26px;
  height: 26px;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 5px;
}
#twitter:hover {
  background-image: url("http://placehold.it/26x26");
}
```

```html
<div class="social" style="float:right">
  <div id="facebook"></div>
  <div id="twitter"></div>
  <div id="link"></div>
</div>
```

The W3C validator points to this line as an issue: https://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/validator?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fpaul.dac-proiect.ro%2Fwp-content%2Fthemes%2Fwpbootstrap%2Fstyle.css&profile=css3&usermedium=all&warning=1&vextwarning=&lang=en

Answer (score 3):

**Note: This only applies if your running an adblocker**

It is your naming conventions so you are using an adblocker of somekind. I am using adguard and it blocks the `.social` class

```
#ad_global_below_navbar, img[width="88"][height="31"], #fb-root, #fb_groups, #flickr_badge_source, #flickr_badge_uber_wrapper, #odklocs0, #odklocs1, #vk_auth, #vk_donate, #vk_group, #vk_groups, #vk_like, #vk_poll, #vk_share, #vkshare0, .DiggThisButton, .addthis_toolbox, .btn-social, .google-buzz-button, .odkl-share-oc, .odkl-share-oc-fc, .odkl-share_button, .share-menu, .share-panel, .social, .social-links, .vk-like, .vk_share_button, a.mrc__plugin_like_button, a.mrc__plugin_recommendations, a.mrc__plugin_share_friends, a.mrc__share, a.odkl-klass, a.odkl-klass-s, a.odkl-klass-stat, a[href="http://del.icio.us/post"], a[href="http://twitter.com/share"] {
  display: none!important;
}
```

---

It seems from inspecting your code your css styles are not being applied to the `#facebook` ids in firefox

Comment: If so, how it is displayed in chrome :(

Comment: That doesnt work, just turned off my adblocker in firefox and the links are still not showing up. Have edited answer.

Comment: Thank you ! I spent hours trying to find why my "class=social" items were not displayed on Firefox with AdBlock Plus...